# Neo4j : Concurrency and memory mapped buffers

Tags: java, multithreading, neo4j

I am launching a batch of traversal on an embedded Neo4J DB 2.0.3.

- 23M nodes
- 87M relations
- 16GB Heap
- Tried different cache settings
- Tried different thread settings ( From 20 to 5 threads )

The Job is running fine for some time (ex: 1h) and then the throughput  slows down dramatically because the threads are spending most of their time waiting for locks.

It looks like the memory buffers (MappedPersistenceWindow) can't be shared by multiple threads, which sounds a bit weird.

Some samples from the thread dump :

```
"taskExecutor-6" - Thread t@17
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <3a67f9f7> (a org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.MappedPersistenceWindow)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.LockableWindow.lock(LockableWindow.java:96)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceWindowPool.acquire(PersistenceWindowPool.java:197)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.acquireWindow(CommonAbstractStore.java:430)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.RelationshipStore.getRecord(RelationshipStore.java:84)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction$3.load(NeoStoreTransaction.java:208)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction$3.load(NeoStoreTransaction.java:198)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.RecordChanges.getOrLoad(RecordChanges.java:63)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.relLoadLight(NeoStoreTransaction.java:1189)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.loadLightRelationship(PersistenceManager.java:109)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager$2.loadById(NodeManager.java:114)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager$2.loadById(NodeManager.java:110)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.cache.AutoLoadingCache.get(AutoLoadingCache.java:93)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getRelationshipForProxy(NodeManager.java:544)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$6.lookupRelationship(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:849)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipProxy.getType(RelationshipProxy.java:141)


"taskExecutor-5" - Thread t@16
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.LockableWindow.markAsInUse(LockableWindow.java:70)
  - locked <6abe6e1> (a org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.MappedPersistenceWindow)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.BrickElement.getAndMarkWindow(BrickElement.java:94)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceWindowPool.acquire(PersistenceWindowPool.java:147)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.acquireWindow(CommonAbstractStore.java:430)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.RelationshipStore.getChainRecord(RelationshipStore.java:325)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.getMoreRelationships(NeoStoreTransaction.java:2331)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.getMoreRelationships(NeoStoreTransaction.java:1390)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getMoreRelationships(PersistenceManager.java:94)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipLoader.getMoreRelationships(RelationshipLoader.java:50)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getMoreRelationships(NodeManager.java:779)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.loadMoreRelationshipsFromNodeManager(NodeImpl.java:577)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getMoreRelationships(NodeImpl.java:540)
  - locked <2b29ed5b> (a org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipIterator.fetchNextOrNull(RelationshipIterator.java:98)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipIterator.fetchNextOrNull(RelationshipIterator.java:36)
  at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:55)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.hasRelationship(NodeImpl.java:644)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.hasRelationship(NodeProxy.java:183)


"taskExecutor-4" - Thread t@15
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <3a67f9f7> (a org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.MappedPersistenceWindow)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.LockableWindow.lock(LockableWindow.java:96)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceWindowPool.acquire(PersistenceWindowPool.java:197)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.acquireWindow(CommonAbstractStore.java:430)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.RelationshipStore.getChainRecord(RelationshipStore.java:325)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.getMoreRelationships(NeoStoreTransaction.java:2331)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.getMoreRelationships(NeoStoreTransaction.java:1390)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getMoreRelationships(PersistenceManager.java:94)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipLoader.getMoreRelationships(RelationshipLoader.java:50)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getMoreRelationships(NodeManager.java:779)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.loadMoreRelationshipsFromNodeManager(NodeImpl.java:577)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getMoreRelationships(NodeImpl.java:540)
  - locked <41fe8c4f> (a org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipIterator.fetchNextOrNull(RelationshipIterator.java:98)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipIterator.fetchNextOrNull(RelationshipIterator.java:36)
  at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:55)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.hasRelationship(NodeImpl.java:644)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.hasRelationship(NodeProxy.java:183)


"taskExecutor-3" - Thread t@14
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <3a67f9f7> (a org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.MappedPersistenceWindow)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.LockableWindow.lock(LockableWindow.java:96)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceWindowPool.acquire(PersistenceWindowPool.java:197)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.acquireWindow(CommonAbstractStore.java:430)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.RelationshipStore.getRecord(RelationshipStore.java:84)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction$3.load(NeoStoreTransaction.java:208)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction$3.load(NeoStoreTransaction.java:198)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.RecordChanges.getOrLoad(RecordChanges.java:63)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.relLoadLight(NeoStoreTransaction.java:1189)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.loadLightRelationship(PersistenceManager.java:109)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager$2.loadById(NodeManager.java:114)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager$2.loadById(NodeManager.java:110)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.cache.AutoLoadingCache.get(AutoLoadingCache.java:93)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getRelationshipForProxy(NodeManager.java:544)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$6.lookupRelationship(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:849)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipProxy.getOtherNode(RelationshipProxy.java:108)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchImpl.next(TraversalBranchImpl.java:145)
  at org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.PreorderDepthFirstSelector.next(PreorderDepthFirstSelector.java:49)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.MonoDirectionalTraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(MonoDirectionalTraverserIterator.java:68)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.MonoDirectionalTraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(MonoDirectionalTraverserIterator.java:35)
  at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:55)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: can you share the cache and heap settings that you used here? perhaps also your messages.log?

Comment: The only heap setting is : -Xmx16g.
I tried with no cache and high performance cache :
    node_cache_array_fraction : 5
    relationship_cache_array_fraction : 5
    node_cache_size : 2G
    relationship_cache_size : 2G
I do not think that messages.log is provided in embedded mode.

Comment: messages.log is there in every mode, just look into your graph-db directory. Also I meant the mmio settings.